# Single site web proxy

Tags: blogger, dynamic, mirror, proxy

I want to create a dynamic mirror or a single site web proxy for my blog on a different domain. I have access to a php based web hosting, I own the content on the original site and due to low traffic I think bandwidth is not a issue at all. What would be the best way to proceed?

To provide some context, my real problem is:
- I have a blog hosted on blogger with a custom domain. (e.g. www.abc.com)
- Blogger as a whole is blocked in some countries which effectively makes my blog blocked effectively.
- I own another domain www.def.com and a hosting and all I want is www.def.com to be a dynamic mirror of www.abc.com.

Redirecting will not work because, it will not really bypass the blocking filters.
I am happy with the service of blogger and I do not really want to move or duplicate things.

Before I did not have this problem because blogger allowed me to use ftp and upload stuff on a different hosting server but is not a n option any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just sign up for [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com). It takes your site and caches it on its network. It may help others reach your blog. I have it set up on my site.

Answer (score 2):

If your host uses Apache and allows mod_proxy you can set up a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.def.com
    ProxyPass / http://www.abc.com
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.abc.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This will have the server query the remote site and return it to the user through the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google help forums it looks like this isn't possible:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=2fa60d7d99454722&hl=en

However there is an export and import option. Could you manually export the main blog and import into a second blog (which your second domain points at)? You would need to do it every time you post, so it's not the best solution. However you may find that easier than setting up your own proxy server.

Comment: I am doing this right now, but copying stuff every time I have a new post is really cumbersome. I hope there will be another option soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to program you can have the second domain pull down the contents of your blog and display it that way. This will not require pointing the domain to your current blog and will act as a proxy so your site can be viewed in countries that block Blogger. Just make sure you don't allow Google to index that content or else you will have duplicate content issues.